# strange opacity transition behavior in Opera and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, transition, opacity, opera

On having some tooltip functionality in my project i came across a behavior difference with opacity transitions. Where FF and IE are doing well here (in my favor, seldom occurance) we see in Opera and Chrome that a overlying div only shows completely up after the transition has finished. 
It is clear that the combination of position:fixed and overflow:hidden on the parent div causes it.

```
.hov {
  background: #E7FE94;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Please see my fiddle-demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/SirDarki/665p2924/26/

While the styling is mostly just *bling* the position:fixed and overflow:hidden is really needed in this case. So two questions arise.

What is the standard behavior in this case (if there is any)?
How to work around?

**EDIT**

Maybe i can clarify the question a bit. There are for sure workarounds to overcome that ugly transition(-bug?). Just hook the moving div over the hidden/fixed-restricted div in the dom tree and all looks well. The real question is:

Is there a (confirmed) misbehave in Opera and Chrome or do i sadly miss something obvious/trivial?

Comment: Why can't you just remove the `overflow: hidden;` ? That seems to fix it in chrome for me

Comment: In short: that has to work in all possble situations, often where some parent div's must have overflow:hidden and position:fixed. Basically that should not affect moving div anyway. In addition, the same behavior can also been seen when the moving div is defined as sibling to the basis div.